# Extract a sample of 1,000,000 from big dirty data using R

Tags: r

Im trying to extract a sample of 1 million rows with 15 columns from a .CSV file which is 825MB (too big to export completely).

A sample of the data can be shown below:

```
2016-10-31,2016-12-31,OEM,GRILLE,Grille,Grille,F231062J00,NISS-GRP,G20 AUTOMATIC W/TOURING PKG,7+ YEARS,AZ,Western,GRILLE SET-RADIATOR,1,255.09,255.09
2016-10-31,2016-12-31,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,TN,South Central,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1076.49,1076.49
2016-07-31,2016-09-30,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,WA,Western,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1076.49,1076.49
2016-04-30,2016-06-30,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,ME,Eastern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1108.79,1108.79
2016-10-31,2016-12-31,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,CA,Western,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1076.49,1076.49
2016-07-31,2016-09-30,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,MO,Central,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1076.49,1076.49
2016-04-30,2016-06-30,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,OH,Central,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1022.67,1022.67
2016-07-31,2016-09-30,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER SE 4WD,7+ YEARS,CT,Eastern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1076.49,1076.49
2016-10-31,2016-12-31,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER SE 4WD,7+ YEARS,NJ,Eastern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1076.49,1076.49
2016-10-31,2016-12-31,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER SE 4WD,7+ YEARS,PA,Eastern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1076.49,1076.49
2016-10-31,2016-12-31,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER SE 4WD,7+ YEARS,OR,Western,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1076.49,1076.49
2016-04-30,2016-06-30,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,MA,Eastern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,3,3261.77,1087.26
2017-01-31,2017-03-31,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER SE 4WD,7+ YEARS,MA,Eastern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,2,2152.98,1076.49
2016-04-30,2016-06-30,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,NJ,Eastern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,3,3229.47,1076.49
2016-04-30,2016-06-30,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,GA,Southern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1076.49,1076.49
2016-07-31,2016-09-30,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,FL,Southern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1076.49,1076.49
2016-10-31,2016-12-31,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,TX,South Central,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1076.49,1076.49
2016-07-31,2016-09-30,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,CA,Western,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1076.49,1076.49
2016-04-30,2016-06-30,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,NY,Eastern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1076.49,1076.49
2016-07-31,2016-09-30,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,CO,Western,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,2,2152.98,1076.49
2016-04-30,2016-06-30,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,UT,Western,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1076.49,1076.49
2016-07-31,2016-09-30,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,GA,Southern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1076.49,1076.49
2016-04-30,2016-06-30,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,CA,Western,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1108.79,1108.79
2016-07-31,2016-09-30,OEM,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,VA,Southern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,1076.49,1076.49
2016-10-31,2016-12-31,RECYCLED,TRUNK LID,Spoiler assy,Spoiler assy graphite,K6030AM817,NISS-GRP,G35 COUPE AUTOMATIC W/LEATHER,7+ YEARS,CA,Western,G35 COUPE REAR SPOILER-WV2,1,200.00,200.00
2016-10-31,2016-12-31,RECYCLED,WHEELS,Wheel, alloy,Wheel, alloy type 1 17" wheel,D03004Y91A,NISS-GRP,MAXIMA SE 20TH ANNIVERSARY EDITION AUTOMATIC,7+ YEARS,MA,Eastern,ALUMINUM WHEEL,3,318.75,106.25
2017-01-31,2017-03-31,RECYCLED,WHEELS,Wheel, alloy,Wheel, alloy type 1 17" wheel,D03004Y91A,NISS-GRP,MAXIMA SE 20TH ANNIVERSARY EDITION AUTOMATIC,7+ YEARS,FL,Southern,ALUMINUM WHEEL,1,375.00,375.00
2016-08-31,2016-10-31,RECYCLED,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,MD,Southern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,312.50,312.50
2016-05-31,2016-07-31,RECYCLED,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,VA,Southern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,468.75,468.75
2016-08-31,2016-10-31,RECYCLED,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,WA,Western,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,268.75,268.75
2016-05-31,2016-07-31,RECYCLED,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,MA,Eastern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,312.50,312.50
2017-02-28,2017-04-30,RECYCLED,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,FL,Southern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,625.00,625.00
2016-11-30,2017-01-31,RECYCLED,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,FL,Southern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,300.00,300.00
2016-10-31,2016-12-31,RECYCLED,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,CO,Western,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,287.50,287.50
2016-10-31,2016-12-31,RECYCLED,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,WV,Southern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,375.00,375.00
2016-10-31,2016-12-31,RECYCLED,QUARTER PANEL,Quarter panel,Quarter panel w/o rear spare carrier SE & LE,G81012W730,NISS-GRP,PATHFINDER,7+ YEARS,NY,Eastern,SERVICE FILE  FENDER-REAR,LH,1,437.50,437.50
```

The major problem is that it has some rows that have more than 15 columns (dirty). I am using the line of code:

```
library(sqldf)
DF <- read.csv.sql("CCC_Data.csv", sql = "select * from file order by random() limit 1000000")
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : line 24 did not have 17 elements
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is missing a reproducible example (i.e. a sample of the file) as well a package for the `read.csv.sql` function. In addition, it's not clear what should happen with the malformed lines of the file.

Comment: you can start by posting some sample data, including the mentioned line 24...
ypou can always try to read in the file using `data.table::fread()`, setting the sep to "", which results in reading the entire line into one column. After that, clean your data before splitting to columns.

Comment: again, reprex data to highlight how the number of columns is irregular would be best, however I'd try `read.csv` and `readr::read_csv` as well. If those throw errors, then edit your post with those (as well as the reprex data).

Comment: the best way to export the data sample is `dput(your_df)`. If the first few lines are representative then `dput(head(your_df))`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fill the missing columns with NA

for the provided sample data (which had no headers), the code below reads the data to a data.table.

```
library( data.table )
dt <- data.table::fread( "./test.csv", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE )
```

use `nrow = 1000000` to limit reading to 1 million rows

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comments. I just edited the data so you can try to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I read in your data with `read_csv` which gave warnings rather than errors. You're missing delimiters in the data which is frame-shifting columns.  More qualified people than me on this forum may give a better answer, but my approach would be:

1. After import look for a column which is predictably inconsistent. Meaning you can write some logic to filter out the inconsistent rows. From the data above looks like rows 1, 26 & 27 are candidates.
2. Filter out those rows so you can perhaps analyse the remaining data
3. Filter only those rows so you can look for logic to substitute in new columns, then combine back into step 2.

`tidyverse` verbs `filter`, `select` and `mutate` should get you there.

Answer (score 0):

Add the filter argument to only keep rows that have 17 fields.  This assumes you have gawk on your PATH or if it is there but not on your path you can include its absolute path.  On Windows you may need to install RTools to get `gawk`.

You may also need `header = FALSE` if there is no header.  If the line endings do not correspond to your platform you may need `eol="\n"` or `eol="\r\n"`

```
DF <- read.csv.sql("CCC_Data.csv", 
  sql = "select * from file order by random() limit 1000000",
  filter = 'gawk "NF==17" FS=,')
```